Title: Issues with Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization in Flutter App Using flutter_appauth
Body:
I'm working on integrating Google OAuth 2.0 into my Flutter application to create Google Calendar events with Google Meet links. However, I’m encountering issues with the authorization process. Below is my Flutter code and a description of the problem I am facing.
Code
dart

Copy code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:flutter_appauth/flutter_appauth.dart'; import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart' as calendar; import 'package:googleapis_auth/googleapis_auth.dart' as auth; import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; void main() { runApp(GoogleMeetsApp()); } class GoogleMeetsApp extends StatelessWidget { @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return MaterialApp( home: MeetsState(), ); } } class MeetsState extends StatefulWidget { @override _MeetsState createState() => _MeetsState(); } class _MeetsState extends State<MeetsState> { final String clientId = '500686653155-i24aakgq6a04ecul97h16qcpg9s64aig.apps.googleusercontent.com'; final String redirectUri = 'https://medstake.com/oauth2redirect'; final List<String> _scopes = [calendar.CalendarApi.calendarScope]; final FlutterAppAuth _flutterAppAuth = FlutterAppAuth(); String _errorMessage = ''; Future<void> _authenticateWithGoogle() async { try { final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result = await _flutterAppAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode( AuthorizationTokenRequest( clientId, redirectUri, scopes: _scopes, ), ); if (result != null && result.accessToken != null) { await _createEvent(result.accessToken!); } else { setState(() { _errorMessage = 'Failed to get access token'; }); print('Failed to get access token'); // Log to console } } catch (e) { setState(() { _errorMessage = 'Error: $e'; }); print('Error during authentication: $e'); // Log to console } } Future<void> _createEvent(String accessToken) async { try { final authClient = await auth.authenticatedClient( http.Client(), auth.AccessCredentials( auth.AccessToken('Bearer', accessToken, DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 1))), null, _scopes, ), ); var calendarApi = calendar.CalendarApi(authClient); var event = calendar.Event( summary: 'Google Meet Meeting', start: calendar.EventDateTime( dateTime: DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 1)), timeZone: 'UTC', ), end: calendar.EventDateTime( dateTime: DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 2)), timeZone: 'UTC', ), conferenceData: calendar.ConferenceData( createRequest: calendar.CreateConferenceRequest( requestId: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(), conferenceSolutionKey: calendar.ConferenceSolutionKey(type: 'hangoutsMeet'), ), ), ); var calendarId = 'primary'; var createdEvent = await calendarApi.events.insert(event, calendarId, conferenceDataVersion: 1); print('Event created: ${createdEvent.htmlLink}'); ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( SnackBar(content: Text('Event created: ${createdEvent.htmlLink}')), ); } catch (e) { setState(() { _errorMessage = 'Failed to create event: $e'; }); print('Error creating event: $e'); // Log to console } } @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Google Meet Integration')), body: Center( child: Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[ ElevatedButton( onPressed: _authenticateWithGoogle, child: Text('Create Google Meet Event'), ), if (_errorMessage.isNotEmpty) Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0), child: Text( _errorMessage, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16), ), ), ], ), ), ); } }
Issue Description
I'm having trouble with the OAuth 2.0 authorization process using flutter_appauth. Specifically:

Authorization Failure: The authorizeAndExchangeCode method seems to fail, and I receive the error message "Failed to get access token."

Console Errors: The console shows the error message "Error during authentication: [error details]." Here are the details of the error:
csharp

Copy code
[Error details]

Google Cloud Console: I have configured the OAuth consent screen, and the redirect URI https://medstake.com/oauth2redirect is properly set up in the Google Cloud Console.


Questions

Authorization Failure: What could be causing the failure to retrieve the access token? Are there any common pitfalls with the flutter_appauth package that I should be aware of?

Error Handling: How can I improve error handling or logging to better diagnose the issue?

OAuth Configuration: Is there something I might have missed in the OAuth configuration that could be causing this issue?


Any help or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried changing versions on flutter_auth
